# React router dom NavLink only works when refresh no when click the nav item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

A react-router-dom `NavLink` only works after refresh not when clicking the nav item.

```
<NavLink
   to="/test"
   activeClassName="active">
   test
</NavLink>
```

I don't get any errors on the page. When I clicked on the NavLink it updated my URL but did not apply the active class, I have to refresh the page to get the active class on the NavLink. Using v5

Answer (score 0):

First you have to import NavLink.then you can directly set activeStyle to the styles you want.

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

```
<NavLink to="/test" activeClassName="active">
 Test
</NavLink>
```

Style your class in the css by the property active:

```
.active{
  color:#3895d3;
 }
```

Comment: the question is not about styling, I can see the style but it only works on refresh... do you how to solve that? perhaps update RRD?